# VBA Multi-sub code for a conditional check on a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to look at the inventory document that I made to check all of our parts. The document is split up into 6 different sheets, 1 for each area. The document has each part with its own row from number, description, (other stuff), min, total, max.

I have an "if" statement that will display in a column to the right of the max if the total is at or below the min to say "Low." In my code I have it go through each row and if it shows "Low" in the "o column" then it will display itself in another sheet that has a table for all of these parts. I can get it to work for 1 sheet but not multiple.

I have a secondary sub that shows the date and time so that our buyer knows when they last checked the document.

For example. If I had 2 sheets with 5 low parts on each (10 total) and I run the code. Only 9 show up. 4 from the first sheet and 5 from the second.

Here is my code.

```
Sub Clear()

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Low_Inventory").ClearContents

Call MoveData1
Call MoveData2

End Sub


Sub MoveData1()


endrow = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
endcolumn = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
repeatrow = Sheet3.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

For xrow = endrow To 2 Step by - 1
    If Sheet1.Cells(xrow, 15) = "Low" Then
        For xcolumn = 1 To endcolumn
          Sheet3.Cells(repeatrow, xcolumn) = Sheet1.Cells(xrow, xcolumn)
        Next
        repeatrow = repeatrow + 1
        
    End If
 If Sheet1.Cells(xrow, 15) = "Low" Then
        Call xdate1
    End If
Next



End Sub


Sub xdate1()

Dim xdate
xdate = Now
endrow = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
endcolumn = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
repeatrow = Sheet3.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

For xrow = endrow To 2 Step by - 1
    If Sheet1.Cells(xrow, 15) = "Low" Then
        For xcolumn = 1 To endcolumn
         Sheet3.Cells(repeatrow, 16) = xdate
        Next
        repeatrow = repeatrow
        
    End If
Next


End Sub


Sub MoveData2()


endrow = Sheet2.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
endcolumn = Sheet2.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
repeatrow = Sheet3.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

For xrow = endrow To 2 Step by - 1
    If Sheet2.Cells(xrow, 15) = "Low" Then
        For xcolumn = 1 To endcolumn
          Sheet3.Cells(repeatrow, xcolumn) = Sheet2.Cells(xrow, xcolumn)
        Next
        repeatrow = repeatrow + 1
        
    End If
 If Sheet2.Cells(xrow, 15) = "Low" Then
        Call xdate2
    End If
Next



End Sub


Sub xdate2()

Dim xdate
xdate = Now
endrow = Sheet2.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
endcolumn = Sheet2.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
repeatrow = Sheet3.Cells(3, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

For xrow = endrow To 2 Step by - 1
    If Sheet2.Cells(xrow, 15) = "Low" Then
        For xcolumn = 1 To endcolumn
         Sheet3.Cells(repeatrow, 16) = xdate
        Next
        repeatrow = repeatrow
        
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Where am I wrong to make this not be an issue anymore?

Comment: So much stuff that needs to be removed and simplified. your two xdate functions have `repeaterow = repeatrow` without adding +1, that may override some of the stuff at some point. Still you should still get the 10 and not 9 from a quick glance. Anyways all of this can be done on a Single Sub that would not give a headache.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @RicardoA If I have 'repeat row = reapeat row + 1' it will show the date + time twice for each row of information. I ended up figuring it out for how I did it. I added a +2 instead of +1 for the repeat row count on the second data mover. How would you clean this up into being 1 sub? I learned VBA 2 months ago with no coding experience prior, for me, if it worked I'm not gonna mess with it so my idea was to repeat it for each sheet. I'm quite happy with the result since it is my own and it works. Please let me know how to clean it up for future reference.